# Getting data from JSON file in different languages using C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, encoding, multilingual

I tried to get data from JSON file into my app using this code
(Hebrew letters appear like this "??"):

```
        private static T PopulateData<T>(string fileName)
    {
        var file = "TestingNav.Data." + fileName;
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        T obj;

        var resourceStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(file);
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(resourceStream, Encoding.Default))
        {
            string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

however, it didn't work on different languages i.e. Hebrew... although I did try to put encoding of different types in it.

the JSON part that the code cant read:

```
{
  "itemName": "Hamburger",
  "name": "Hamburger 52",
  "description": "Hamburger 52 Y/O",
  "itemDescription": "טעים מאוד hamburger with Angus beef grilled to perfection",
  "itemRating": 4.5
},
```

update:

```
        private static T PopulateData<T>(string fileName)
    {
        var file = "TestingNav.Data." + fileName;
        T obj;

        var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(T)).Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(file);
        string text = "";
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(text);
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222637/discussion-on-question-by-shahar-band-getting-data-from-json-file-in-different-l).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite simple thank you for all the massive help @Panagiotis Kanavos @dbc @Heretic Monkey

the solution:

```
        private static T PopulateData<T>(string fileName)
    {
        var file = "TestingNav.Data." + fileName;
        T obj;

        var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(T)).Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(file);
        string text = "";
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1255)))
        {
            text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(text);
        }

        return obj;
    }
```